# Java -Executable JAR- Error when Creating FileWriter : FileNotFoundException access is denied

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I have a program that have a file in which I write the progress I've done, so if the program is closed I can just re-read what I already did.

So if the file doesn't exist (first time I launch the program), I create it, and after that I write in it.

This work while I work with Eclipse. But since I exported to an Executable JAR, I have an error if the file already exists ! That is, I can create the file and write in it the first time, but not if I close and re-launch the program.

Here's the code :

```java
        String donePath = "./done.txt";
        try {
            File doneFile = new File(donePath);
            doneFile.createNewFile();
            allreadyDone = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String(
                                Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(donePath))).split("\n")));
            doneFileWriter =  new FileWriter(donePath, true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and I'm getting :

```java
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\done.txt (Accès refusé)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:292)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:156)
        at java.base/java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:82)
        at =============.Main.main(Main.java:51)
```

Answer (score 0):

I run your program (on Windows 10) with the extension of

1. printing the work already done
2. writing something (current time)
3. a finally-block that flushes and closes the doneFileWriter.

With the finally block everything is OK.
Without the finally block nothing is actually written.

I would expect "Accès refusé" if the log file is already open (by a different running instance).
Or if you run your code first with one user that owns the log file. And then use a different user for the next run, that has not write access.

You use the rather modern java.nio.Paths. So I suggest some type changes and debugging output:

```
Path donePath = Paths.get("./done.txt");
try {
  File doneFile = donePath.toFile();
  UserPrincipal owner = Files.getOwner(donePath);
  String permissions = PosixFilePermissions.toString(
                         Files.getPosixFilePermissions(donePath));
  System.out.println(
    String.format("abs path:%s, owner:%s, can write:%b, permissions:%s", 
                  doneFile.getAbsolutePath(), owner.getName(), 
                  doneFile.canWrite(), permissions));
  allreadyDone = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String(
                   Files.readAllBytes(donePath)).split("\n")));
```

What operating system do you use?
Which Java implementation (vendor/version)?
And what is your debug output?

Comment: Thank you for your help ! However that doesn't work even if I have just one instance, and I run it with same user every time. I also tried to run it with admin,but I had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the createNewFile() among an if-statement, so that if it is successfully created it goes ahead, and if it does not it simply outputs "File already exists".

```
 try {           
            
          File myObj = new File(filename);
                      if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
                        System.out.println("File created: " + myObj.getName());      
                      } else {
                        System.out.println("File already exists.");          
                      }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                      System.out.println("An error occurred.");
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```